# Calculate the rank and apply it following an order

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions, dense-rank

I want to calculate the dense rank over a group by clause and set my rank in order of my line id i.e the smallest ids get the first rank and so on.

I am able to retrieve the dense rank of my lines but the rank applied rank is not in the order I want. Sample data:

```
id          rang                 prop1       prop2        prop3     prop4                          
----------- -------------------- ----------- ----------- --------- -----
1244834     2                    609         96          0,02       0,00           
1244835     2                    609         96          0,02       0,00           
1244836     2                    609         96          0,02       0,00           
1244837     1                    609         96          0,00       0,01           
1244838     1                    609         96          0,00       0,01           
1244839     1                    609         96          0,00       0,01
```

my request is as follow :

```
select id,
       DENSE_RANK() over (order by prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4) rang
       prop1,
       prop2,
       prop3,
       prop4,
from mytable
where ...
order by id
```

I want the calculated rank to be applied following my id column order, knowing that the ids are consecutive.

My real data has 15 more properties that are used for the ranking, they are not usefull for the ordering

In my case I want rang = 1 for id 124834, 124835, 124836 and rang = 2 for id 124837, 124838, 124839

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly then you first need to find minimum id per `prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4` group and calculate rank on that:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, MIN(id) OVER (PARTITION BY prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4) AS min_id
    FROM (VALUES
        (1244834, 609, 96, 0.02, 0.00),
        (1244835, 609, 96, 0.02, 0.00),
        (1244836, 609, 96, 0.02, 0.00),
        (1244837, 609, 96, 0.00, 0.01),
        (1244838, 609, 96, 0.00, 0.01),
        (1244839, 609, 96, 0.00, 0.01)
    ) t(id, prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4)
)
SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY min_id) AS rnk
FROM cte
ORDER BY rnk, id
```

Comment: That is what I needed, I didn't know the `min() over` method, that's clever. Thanks a lot. I used `dense_rank() over (partition by prop1 order by min_id)` to fullfill my needs

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you just need to change the direction of `prop3` from Ascending to Descending:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (1244834,2,609,96,0.02,0.00),           
                 (1244835,2,609,96,0.02,0.00),           
                 (1244836,2,609,96,0.02,0.00),           
                 (1244837,1,609,96,0.00,0.01),           
                 (1244838,1,609,96,0.00,0.01),           
                 (1244839,1,609,96,0.00,0.01)) V(id, rang, prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4))
SELECT VTE.id,
       VTE.rang,
       VTE.prop1,
       VTE.prop2,
       VTE.prop3,
       VTE.prop4,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY prop1, prop2, prop3 DESC, prop4) AS Ranking
FROM VTE;
```

Comment: I thought about this solution but all my properties are needed for the grouping but cannot be used for the ordering as they are not always in the order in my example. Sorry if my description wasn't clear enough, thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: Seems that Salman A worked out the logic you need @hunB . Good to see you got the answer you needed.